# How to properly return updated state when using getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-lifecycle

For example we have such state:

`state = { hasSomething: true, anotherKey: '', ... }`

and we should update only 'hasSomething':

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.accessKey === 'admin') {
            return {
                hasSomething: false,
            };
        }
        return null;
    }
```

do we need to destruct the prevState when we return new state?
for example like this:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.accessKey === 'admin') {
        return {
            ...prevState,
            hasSomething: false,
        };
    }
    return null;
}
```

or we don't need it?
i checked the console.log(this.state) and it returns the whole local state if im not make a prevState destructing.

i can't find this information in official react documentation :(

P.S. this logic just an example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation says `It should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.` (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops). It is not cleared the state when you return only part of it, so it works like `setState` (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). The `setState` documentation says
`You may optionally pass an object as the first argument to setState() instead of a function. This performs a shallow merge of stateChange into the new state.`, so you don't need to destruct the previous state.